# NEST DBGeography

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Nest 6.2.0 to connect to elastic search.

I am trying to map a class containing DBGeography objects and I have tried adding the [GeoShape] tag and I get the following error.

> ServerError = {ServerError: 400Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "failed to parse" CausedBy: "Type: not_x_content_exception Reason: "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes""}

The code  I am using to Create the index and document are:

```
// Create an index
response = Connection.CreateIndex(indexName, c => c
                   .Mappings(ms => ms
                   .Map<RACE.DataModels.EventModels.Event.Route>(m => m
                   .AutoMap<RACE.DataModels.EventModels.Event.Route>()
                   )
                   )
                   );

// Add document to index
result = Connection.Index(obj, i => i
                    .Index(indexName));
```

Also, here is the code for the Route object which I am trying to add to the index.

```
public partial class Route : BaseClass
        {
              [Key]
              public Guid ID { get; set; }

              [Required]
              [Display(Name = "Event")]
              public Guid EventID { get; set; }

              [Required]
              [Display(Name = "Route Name")]
              public string Name { get; set; }

              [Display(Name = "Description")]
              public string Description { get; set; }

              [Required]
              [Display(Name = "Path Type")]
              public int PathType { get; set; }

              [GeoShape]
              [Required]
              [Display(Name = "Route Path")]
              public DbGeography Path { get; set; }

              //[GeoShape]
              [Ignore]
              public string PathWKT { get { return Path.WellKnownValue.WellKnownText; } }

              [GeoShape]
              [Display(Name = "Start")]
              public DbGeography Start { get; set; }

              [GeoShape]
              [Display(Name = "End")]
              public DbGeography End { get; set; }

              [Display(Name = "Laps")]
              public int Laps { get; set; }

              [Display(Name = "Status")]
              public int Status { get; set; }

              [Ignore]
              [ForeignKey("EventID")]
              public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

              [Ignore]
              [ForeignKey("RouteID")]
              public virtual List<Gateway> Gateways { get; set; }

        }
```

Is DBGeography stopping the object from being correctly mapped, and how can I correctly map a DBGeography object to GeoShape?

Answer (score 0):

NEST doesn't know how to serialize `DbGeography` types. The options you have are:

1. Write a JsonConverter that can serialize a `DbGeography` to geo_shape geoJSON that Elasticsearch supports, and [hook up `JsonNetSerializer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_jsonnetserializer) from [`Nest.JsonNetSerializer` nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST.JsonNetSerializer/) to use this converter.

or

2. Map the `DbGeography` type to the respective `IGeoShape` type that NEST knows how to serialize, and use `IGeoShape` on your document POCO. You could probably leverage NetTopologySuite and types such as [`WKTReader`](https://nettopologysuite.github.io/html/class_net_topology_suite_1_1_i_o_1_1_w_k_t_reader.html) to help with the conversion.

Elasticsearch 6.2.0 supports [geo_shape](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html) input as [WKT](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html#input-structure) but this is not yet exposed in NEST; there's [an open issue to add it in the next release](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/3256). At the very least, I expect this to support deserializing WKT to NEST's `IGeoShape`.